# myshell: Child processes do not run in the background

Tags: c, shell, process, pipe, signals

I'm writing myshell program.

it should supportpipe processing. It should also recognize the '&' at the end of the command and run the child process in the background if the '&' is attached.

The problem with my program is,
*ls | grep txt* works well, but *ls | greptxt &* is not working.

To this end, I declared globally the *pid* array that stores the IDs of the generated child processes and the *reaped_id* array that stores the IDs of the reaped child processes.

The second process are blocked(sigsuspended) if the first child process had not been reapped. Also, when the first process ends, sigchld handler sends a SIGCONT signal to the second process if the second process has been created that moment.

Debugging results in Sigchld handler:  it does not send SIGCONT signals to the second process even after the second process has been blocked

More specifically, the incremental *pcount* (number of child processes created) in the parent process is not reflected in the Sigchld handler.(globally defined) Here's a part of my shell.

```
       while(buffer[idx] != '\0'){
                
            /*check if it is piped process*/
            pipe_start_flag = pipe_end_flag;  // if last process was piping process, then this process is a piped process

            parse_line(&buffer[idx], argv, &idx, &pipe_end_flag); // parse until it meets '\0' or '|'(assign its (index-1) on idx)

            pid[pcount] = Fork(); 
            if(pid[pcount] == 0){
                int big_bro_idx = pcount - 1; // index of last process
                if(!pipe_start_flag && pipe_end_flag){
                    dup2(fd[WRITEEND],STDOUT_FILENO); 
                    close(fd[READEND]); 
                }
                else if(pipe_start_flag && !pipe_end_flag){
                    dup2(fd[READEND], STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(fd[WRITEEND]);  
                    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "second process spawned\n", 23); // debugger 


                    while(reaped_id[big_bro_idx] == 0){ // while last process are executing. If last process terminate, this will be its pid  
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "this line works\n", 15); // debugger code 
                        Sigsuspend(&blocking_mask);
                    }
                }   
                if(execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0){
                    printf("%s: command not found\n", argv[0]);
                    exit(1);              
                }    
            }
            
            else{ // parent process"
                close(fd[WRITEEND]); 
                if(!bg){
 
                    while(reaped_id[pcount] <= 0 && sigtstp_flag == false){
                        Sigsuspend(&blocking_mask); // wait for sigchld 
                    }
                    sigtstp_flag = false; // reset flag to false(it changed at sigtstp_flag)
                }
                else; // background process
                    
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, "pcount increased\n", 17); // debugging code 
                ++pcount; 
            }
        
            ++idx; 
        }
```

Next is my SIGCHLD handler.

```
void sigchld_handler(int sig){
     sigset_t mask, prev; 
     int status; 
     int olderrno = errno; 


    Sigfillset(&mask); 
    Sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev); 

    while((reaped_id[reap_count] = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "process terminated\n", 19); 
        reap_count ++; 
    }
    
    printf("%d %d %d %d ", pid[reap_count], reap_count, pcount, reaped_id[reap_count -1]); 
    if(pid[reap_count] > 0 || WIFSTOPPED(status)){ // if there is little brother process 
        Kill(pid[reap_count], SIGCONT);  // send SIGCONT singal to blocked sibling process 
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "I alarmed my sibling", 20); // debuggging code; not executed
    }

    Sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev, NULL); 
    errno = olderrno; 
}
```

[image]

process graph:

1. Shell spawn both child processes
2. The second process is blocked because the first process is not finished
3. First process terminated
4. Sigcont signal should be sent from Sigchld handler to second process but not.
   (It shows that the *pcount* is increased, but when I print a *pcount* in sigchld handler, it doesn't increase at all.)

I've been up all night for this problem. If you need a full code to execute, we will send it to you.

If there is anything I need to supplement, please tell me and I will supplement it right away.

Comment: You are leaving file descriptors open.  The general boiler plate code is `dup2(fd[WRITEEND],STDOUT_FILENO); close(fd[WRITEEND]);close(fd[READEND]);`. Close both sides of the pipe.  You don't want 2 copies of the dup'd descriptor.  dup it and close it.

Comment: Note that both processes in a 2-part pipeline should run concurrently.  In general, the first process may generate more data than can fit in the pipe buffer (usually 64 KiB these days, but it used to be just 5 KiB), and will therefore be blocked waiting for another process to read some data from the pipe, so it may never terminate if the second process is suspended.  The same applies to multi-stage pipelines; all the processes should run concurrently to prevent blockages (and benefit from multi-core chips).

Comment: Running the process in the background simply means that you don't wait for the last child to exit (or, indeed, any of the other children).  You go about the ordinary business of the shell, spotting when processes in the pipeline exit via signal handling and/or variations on the theme of `wait()`/`waitpid()`.  Note that nasty people (e.g. me) could confuse your shell by giving it children that it doesn't know about when it is started.  It's not a likely problem, but your shell shouldn't throw conniptions if it collects the exit information from a child it has no knowledge of.

Comment: Note that the parent process needs to close both ends of the pipe, not just the write end of it.  That's partly for cleanliness (it will run out of file descriptors if you don't close the ones it isn't going to use) and partly to make sure that processes writing to the pipe get a SIGPIPE signal or an error (if they've blocked SIGPIPE) when there are no processes left to read from the pipe.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffeler  Thanks a lot. I seem to have missed the concept of dup2. It was a great help in getting the concept.

Comment: @Jonathan As you said, I modified the code and confirmed that another problem occurs (Bad file descriptor). If you have time, could you check it out? I think it'll be a big help.

Comment: Please don't add comments about changed code before changing the code.  It wastes people's time if they happen to be getting alerts via the app (which is deprecated, but it still works and I still use it).